# How can I use a custom SQL statement in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, pervasive

I need to create a Crystal report with custom SQL code that I have written. Is this possible? I've looked at other posts asking similar questions but none of them work for me. I'm using Crystal Reports 2008.

Comment: What have you tried?  What results did you get?  You said it didn't work.  Did it give an error or wrong results or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to an SAP knowledgebase article on creating a Crystal Report using a Command. This allows you to use your own SQL:
https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1531012